# Stripe creates a ANOTHER Cookie while EXCLUDE in GA(Cross Domain)

Tags: cookies, stripe-payments, google-tag-manager, hubspot

i ma having cookie issue.
I have excluded STRIPE in google analytics.(exclusion list)

but the stripe creating a NEW cookie when user go to stripe checkout

url is checkout.stripe.com/pay/cs_live

once user lands on this url it creates another cookie and it is not using a previously created _ga cookie,

so I think its a Cross domain issue and I am having this issue since 5 days and I have tried all things but nothing applied properly

RECAP - GA Cookie works for other pages or it won't chenage anything on the other pages but above url creates a NEW cookie

Please help me out!

Comment: I do not understand your issue. Your ga setup does not set cookie on the stripe domain in any case. Referral exclusion means that stripe.com (in this case) is ignored as a referrer, so that GA does not start a new session when people return from your payment gateway. It has nothing to do with cookies (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en). Stripe.com also uses GA, so they set a _ga cookie, but this is unrelated to your own GA installation.

Comment: Hi Eike Pierstorff, now I have the clear scenario after reading your comment and thank you so much for this! gotcha!